# Visual Temporary Bug on profile page change picture

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture

when you are on profile page and responses tab is active and there are some responses regarding questions and you change your picture to one of the options available (in my case identicon, gravatar) all the thumbs in responses will switch to the same image you just selected.
after that when you refresh your page everything is ok.

anyone else having this issue or just me?

Comment: Huh. Yep. I see it too.

Comment: Wow, nice bug! @Anna since it's affecting all sites isn't this better be migrated to MSE? Or reported there as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's fine to report bugs on per-site metas. We would not accomplishing anything particularly productive with a migration here, especially because this issue has likely existed for months and nobody even noticed until now. :)